# Going through Access Reports is slow

Tags: ms-access, indexing, reporting

I am new to Access. I have a Access database that will generate a report that I can index through. My report is over information about individuals and details about them. The report also has a "subreport" over item(s) each individual has. When I run the report the bottom status bar says running query for a few minute. When the query is done I have about 200 items I can index through. When I say index through I mean there are a few arrows at the bottom of the screen where I can click on and view the next, previous, first, or last item in the report. This is where the problem comes in...

When I click any of the arrows at the bottom, of the page the database has to run the query again. If I click the arrow for the last item in the report the database will query again for a few minutes again. If I click the arrow for the next or previous item in the report the database only queries for a few seconds.

How can I stop access from having to run the query again each time I click the next, previous, last, or first arrows?

I appreciate any and all help. Thank you

Comment: A simple solution is to take your query and change it into a 'Make Table' query, then base the report off that table. Assuming you have a button on a form to run the report, just add VBA code to test if the table exists, delete it if found, run the 'make table' query, then launch the report.

Comment: I like that idea. I will try it. move your comment to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using a pre-created DB or not, but you say you're new to Access and you tagged this with "Indexing".  "Indexing" is a concept where your tables are sorted based on often-used fields.  Have you properly indexed your tables?  That may be part of the bottleneck.

You could also try using the concept of Paging.  To do this in Access, you would create a Ranking field in your query to order and number the records.  Then, you can trap the KeyPress of the Previous and Next buttons and filter your page accordingly.  For instance, if you're on the 2nd page and you're showing 10 records at a time, then the query behind your report changes to:

```
SELECT * FROM MyQuery WHERE MyRankingField BETWEEN 30 and 39
```

Or, as Wayne suggested, you could simply base your report off of the result of a Make Table query.